# Simple Drop Down List from Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This seems like it should be in Rails A1, but I can't find it any where.  I have a bunch of locations stored in a Location table, made up of text fields City, County, Country etc.  (This should have all been normalised out in my opinion, but there you go...).

A user can search by Location, and they enter into the separate search fields.  At the moment, I'd like the Country such box to be a drop down list of countries.  I currently get the list of countries in the db as follows:

```
@countries = Location.find(:all, :select=>"DISTINCT country")
```

The search box is currently just a text field:

```
<%= f.text_field :country,{:placeholder => "Country",:size=>20 } %>
```

But I'd like that to be a drop down box of the countries that are already in the @countries variable.  It will just pass the country as a string.  I'm a complete Newbie to Rails and even the basics are flumaxing me...Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `name` is the actual name of the county in your country model:

```
 <%= f.select(:country, @countries.map(&:name), {:include_blank => 'Select a Country'}) %>
```

You could do differently, having the value of the field different from the value displayed. Documentation [lives here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html).

FYI, I usually use a very convenient gem named [Carmen](https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails) to handle country lists etc...

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It's a Location model rather than a Country model, so I'm pulling out a list of distinct country fields into an array.  So with a slight amendment to change (&:name) to (&:country) it worked!.  I will definitely take a look at your Gem, as my who Location model this is just wrong!